# sum() function gives wrong answer in hiveql

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I was playing around with a simple dataset that you can find [here](https://github.com/verterse/experiments/blob/main/CauseofDeath.csv).

No matter what I do, calling the `SUM()` aggregate function on the 4th column of the given data set returns the wrong answer.

Here is the exact code that I have used:

```
create database beep_boop;

use beep_boop;

create table cause (year INT, sex STRING, cause STRING, value INT)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as textfile
tblproperties("skip.header.line.count" = "1");

load data inpath '/user/verterse/CauseofDeath.csv' into table cause;

select sum(value) from cause;
```

The answer that I get is 11478567 as shown in the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLg2W.png).

But using the `SUM()` in MS Excel gives an answer of 12745563.

I tried deleting the table/database and recreating them from scratch. I tried uploading the csv file again. I tried using different datatypes like INT and BIGINT for the value column. I tried skipping and not skipping the header line. Nothing works. I also know that the file is being read completely because `select count(*) from cause;` returns a correct answer of 1016.

P.S.: I am new to Hadoop, Hive and big data in general.

Comment: Check select * from cause where value is null. Probably some rows are parsed in a wrong way because contain special characters like tabs \t

Comment: @leftjoin I think you are correct. It returns a bunch of rows. I tried ```select count(*) from cause where value is null``` and got 200. How can I fix this?

Comment: check the csv  maybe there are extra delimiters and special characters and fix. First investigate the reason. Only after that think how to fix